# Xamarin.Forms ControlTemplate binding fails after control first drawn

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a `ControlTemplate` to modify the appearance of a radioButton in Xamarin.Forms.
I borrowed/updated it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton#redefine-radiobutton-appearance

It looks great, and the appearance is perfect when the page is created.
I want the image in the radiobutton to change depending on a binding, which it does not do.
The binding property gets modified, `OnPropertyChanged()` gets called, but the binding is not getting triggered.

Here is the general appearance (with two of these `RadioButton`s side by side)

[image]

Again, the appearance and the `Converter` and everything work just fine, but only when the page is first drawn.

Here is the ControlTemplate

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
    <Frame 
               BackgroundColor="#30888888"
               HasShadow="False"
               HeightRequest="{TemplateBinding HeightRequest}"
               WidthRequest="{TemplateBinding WidthRequest}"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
               Padding="0">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Accent" />
                            <Setter TargetName="check"
                                        Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="1" />
                            <Setter TargetName="checkrim"
                                        Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="1" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBackgroundColour}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter TargetName="check"
                                        Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="checkrim"
                                        Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="0" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid Margin="4"
                WidthRequest="100">
            <ContentPresenter Margin="6" />

            <Grid WidthRequest="20"
               HeightRequest="20"
                    Padding="0"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Start">

                <Ellipse x:Name="unckecd"
                            Stroke="White"
                            StrokeThickness="2"
                            Fill="Transparent"
                            Margin="0"
                            WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />

                <Ellipse x:Name="checkrim"
                            Stroke="Accent"
                            StrokeThickness="2"
                            Fill="Transparent"
                            Margin="0"
                            WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />

                <Ellipse x:Name="check"
                            Fill="Accent"
                            Margin="1,1,0,0"
                            WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And the `Style` of my `RadioButton`

```
<Style x:Key="FancyRadioButton" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate"
        Value="{DynamicResource RadioButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

And my `RadioButton`

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource FancyRadioButton}"
                Value="{x:Static gdl90Types:UdpTransmitMode.UdpUnicast}"
                WidthRequest="150"
                HeightRequest="103">

<RadioButton.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" Spacing="0" Margin="0, -3">                                            
        <Image Source="{Binding Source=ColourPresetSetting, 
                            ConverterParameter=unicast,
                            Converter={StaticResource ResourceImageFromThemeConverter}}"
                    Margin="22,0"
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    />              
        <Label Text="UDP UNICAST" TextColor="{DynamicResource MediumContrastTextColour}" />
    </StackLayout>
</RadioButton.Content>
```

All I want is for the `Image` in the `RadioButton` to notice the property `ColourPresetSetting` changing, to update the image.
It does it when first drawn, but no longer after that.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in your bindingContext or bound property or used Converter, is there any obvious errors shown in xaml binding log pane ?

Comment: It binds fine (when the page is presented), and the contect doesn't (cannot) change. Converter is fine - it just doesn't get called, becuase the binding gets 'lost', somehow. The property changes just fine, and OnPropertyChanged gets executed every time.

Comment: @DefenestrationDay I test it at my side, and I also can not get image source when loading RadioButton, seems that can not get binding data.